# How do you install your Android Studio app onto an LG Smart Watch Sport?

Tags: applications, adb, usb-debugging, debug

I am building an application to run on a smartwatch using Android Studio, and I want to install it onto my LG Smart Watch Sport, but I do not know how to do this with this watch. That's because you can't connect it to a computer; the watch itself is charged by placing it on a charging stand, but I don't see any outlets on the watch.

To debug using wifi, all the sources I have found say you need to connect it via USB, and I can't connect it via bluetooth. Does andybody know if it is even possible to install your own Android Studio apps onto the LG Smart Watch Sport? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install your application onto an LG Smart Watch Sport, you must do it either via WiFi *or* Bluetooth because the watch doesn't have a Micro USB port or any port at all. That is why I did it via WiFi.

**How to do this on a Mac**

1. Enable WiFi debugging on your device, using the same WiFi as your machine. Keep in mind the IP Adress of the device.
2. Type `cd Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools` in Terminal to acces the platform-tools directory.
3. Now type in `./adb connect your.ip.adress.here:5555`

The problem for me was that I was always told to type in `adb connect`, and not `./adb connect`. For some reason, that is the only way it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [Creating and Running Wearable Apps](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/creating.html)

From The Google Android Developers website .  It provides a walkthrough on how to do it